# Error Deploying Worklight project

Tags: sql, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am running the sample Module 6.1 from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/

I am getting the following error when starting the worklight server:

Unexpected exception during transaction, rollback: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed extracting adapter name from adapter folder

Transaction rollback: 1535419154 (new:true; completed:false; rollbackOnly:false)
FWLSE0074E: Failed synchronizing adapters from database.
                                  com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl$ClusterSyncAdaptersTransaction.run(DeployServiceImpl.java:441)
                                  com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl$ClusterSyncAdaptersTransaction.run(DeployServiceImpl.java:420)
                                  com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils.doInTransaction(RssBrokerUtils.java:119)
                                  com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DeployServiceImpl.syncAdaptersFromDBTransaction(DeployServiceImpl.java:417)
                                  com.worklight.gadgets.bean.ClusterDataSynchronizationTask.step(ClusterDataSynchronizationTask.java:39)
                                  com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:98)

Comment: How did you deploy the adapter?

Comment: Right clicked on the SQLAdapter > Run As > Deploy Worklight Adapter

Comment: Are you using the Development Edition (Eclipse Worklight Studio plug-in)? What is the database you are working with against?

Comment: Hi Idan,I am actually runninh Eclipse in 2 environments, IOS and Windows. The IOS Eclipse has this error which I believe is something wrong with the Worklight studio install itself. I may abandon this thread and continue debugging the problem on windows: "Can't get cities list. Check database connection"

Answer (score 2):

I know this is about two years too late, but I just ran into this issue myself and was able to resolve it through some guessing. In case anyone wanders in here from Google...

1. Stop your Liberty Worklight Development Server
2. Right-click on it and select "Clean Server on Next Start"
3. Start your Liberty server again
4. Re-install your adapters

I have not run into the same problem again since doing this. I'm not sure if there was an issue with my adapter names or if it was just a fluke, but I will update if I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. Seems there was a problem with my Eclipse install, or Java on Windows. So I switched back to causing my Eclipse and Java installed on IOS and all is working. Also, the IBM documentation was unclear, but now that I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar in my Project\server\lib folder.